# No shardIdentity document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, backup, sharding

Having a sharded cluster in production which has been running for a good year now without issues. Everything is on 4.0, classic 3-3-3(config) + 2 mongos.

While revisiting our back-up strategy i stumped upon [this step](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/#optional-for-any-csrs-hostname-or-replica-set-name-changes-update-shard-metadata-in-each-shard-s-identity-document).

I tried finding that value on every node (mongos, primaries, secondaries) and none of them have a shardIdentity.

```
mongos> db.system.version.find()
{ "_id" : "featureCompatibilityVersion", "version" : "4.0" }
{ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 5 }
```

This thing looks important and is part of `STARTUP2` phase.

For the sake of testing and documenting our back-ups, i followed all the steps from the "[Restore Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/)" documentation. At the end of it:

- `sh.status()` is looking good, i'm seeing the shards
- `rs.status()` is also good
- A standalone `mongod` gives me the proper stats on restored data
- `mongod` output seems fine..

But then `db.coll.stats()` fails with :

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot accept sharding commands if sharding state has not been initialized with a shardIdentity document",
        "code" : 203,
        "codeName" : "ShardingStateNotInitialized",
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1548184216, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1548184216, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

And i can see this error from `mongod`:

`I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: sharding state is not yet initialized`

So far i tried:

- `sh.enableSharding()` returns true (1) but doesn't change anything
- Been through `https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Sharding-Internals#sharding-component-initialization`
- Double checked on our production cluster and no shardIdentity there.

So, how does one enforce a shardIdentify or generate one? How do you find out the "shard name" because i couldn't find such a thing. And, well, why would `sh.status()` give the proper result but cannot associate its shards with the current data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I didn't want to mess around with the admin database but it seemed it was the only thing to do.

#### Gather information

`sh.status()` on a mongos will give the shards name needed and the shard cluster id.
Something like that:

```
"clusterId" : ObjectId("3b743bf3134df1f277980ard")
...
shards:
        {  "_id" : "shardname1",  "host" : "[host:port]",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "shardname2",  "host" : "[host:port]",  "state" : 1 }
```

#### For each replica set

- Get on the primary, select the admin database

Then:

```
db.system.version.insert({
    "_id" : "shardIdentity",
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("3b743bf3134df1f277980ard"),
    "shardName" : "REPLICA_SHARD_NAME",
    "configsvrConnectionString" : "conf/[host]"
})
```

See [Shard Aware](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-sharded-cluster/index.html#prerequisites).

- Reboot all replica set members